# How can I rewrite the datatable on mysql server in R?

Tags: mysql, r, database, connection

I use Mac Computer, installed MySQL server and MySQL workbench. It is work to connect the MySQL server. But when I tried to write the table into MySQL database, it did not show the row value but only the table name and columns name.

Moreover, when I want to **rewrite** the data table, it is shown the error on R studio:

```
#Connect to MySQL
library(RMySQL)
mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user=user, password=password, dbname='testing', host=host)
#Create testing data and store it
df = data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c('a', 'b', 'c'))
dbWriteTable(mydb, value = df, name = "testing_1", append = TRUE)
dbDisconnect(mydb)
```

## Error Message:

Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
could not run statement: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

What should I do? Thank you.

Comment: You should use the overwrite arg :
`dbWriteTable(mydb, value = df, name = "testing_1", append = TRUE, overwrite = TRUE)`

Comment: shown Error: overwrite and append cannot both be TRUE

Comment: Sorry, use `dbWriteTable(mydb, value = df, name = "testing_1", overwrite = TRUE)`

Comment: I tried and not work. Same Error Message: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version.

Comment: Since I am not a MySQL user, I'm afraid I can provide you the solution. It seems to be a configuration issue, check this : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data-local.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to install version 5 of MySQL, and the problem is solved. Might be R studio really do not support the newest version 8 of MySQL.